# Why are my defined strings printing to the console as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined, spotify

I've written a very simple application that pulls all the tracks off of a spotify playlist. First, it gets the track JSON objects using an AJAX request and puts them in an array called `tracks[]`.

Next, I iterate through this array, and in each iteration I pull out the strings for the name of the song and the artist for each track. I put these in a concentrated string. This string is then stored in a new array called `complete`. This is done for each track.

Essentially, `complete` is an array that looks something like

```
[
   "Sympathy for The Devil, The Rolling Stones",
   "Come Together, The Beatles",
   ...
]
```

At this point I have a strange issue. According to chrome's debugger, the array `complete` has all of the correct values inside of it. However, when I attempt to `console.log` any element of `complete` I end up with the value 'undefined'. Stranger yet, if I `console.log` the expression I use to get the two strings and stitch them it prints the correct value.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it so it can `console.log` the correct values

Here is the code that iterates through stored JSON objects, stores them in new array,  and prints:

```
function print() {
    for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for(var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
            try {
               //this logs correct
               console.log(tracks[x].items[n].track.name + " " + tracks[x].items[n].track.artists[0].name);

               //these have correct value
               var deb = (tracks[x].items[n].track.name + " " + tracks[x].items[n].track.artists[0].name);
               complete[z] = deb;
                z++;

               console.log(deb); //throws no error, prints fine
               console.log(complete[z]); //prints undefined 

            } catch(err) {
                //no exception ever thrown
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't do too much JS, sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Where did you declare `complete` as an array and `z` as an int?

Comment: @Œlrim right at the start of the script, well before this function is called: `var complete = new Array(400);` If this is incorrect I apologize, I don't do much JS if you can't tell ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after assigning `complete[z]`, you are incrementing z. When printing, you are not accessing `complete[z]` anymore, but `complete[z+1]` which is not yet defined. Try moving the incrementation after the `console.log` command.

Comment: Aha that would do it (a begginer mistake, I'm ashamed!). As usual, I shouldn't be programming at 10:30 at night. Also @relic thanks for your honesty :D. Lemme test out to be sure and I'll accept in a min

Comment: Yup, thats the problem. Thank you. Won't let me accept for 6 min so I'll do it once it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your example above, you've incremented `z` (which I assume was defined earlier somewhere?) after setting the value on your array. So when setting the value on the array, you've set it to `complete[5]` (or whatever) but you're logging `complete[6]` which is most likely outside the range of your array.